# Multiple SubQuery expressions : Hive

Tags: hive

I am executing one hive query in my db in which i am joining 3 table(table1,table2,table3) and then comparing  table1 year column with 3 other table(table4,table5,table6) using sub queries. I'm using below query.

```
     select * from  table1 A INNER JOIN table2 B ON A.id =b.id 
     inner JOIN table3 c  ON A.id = c.id 
     and c.country ="India"
     where (A.year)< (select year4 from table4) 
     and (A.year1)< (select year5 from table5 ) 
     and (A.year1)< (select year5 from table5) 
     and  (A.year1)< (select year6 from table6)  limit 10;
```

but its giving me below error:

```
    Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Unsupported SubQuery Expression
    'year1': Only 1 SubQuery expression is supported.
```

someone please guide me how should i handle this.

EXPECTED OUTPUT[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want. It is no obvious to assess what you want to do from this invalid query only.

Comment: @GMB, I have updated the question.Please help me to modify my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all tables in a join condition and then only you can compare year.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM  
TABLE1 A 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID =B.ID 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 C  ON A.ID = C.ID AND C.COUNTRY ="India"
INNER JOIN TABLE4 T4 ON T4.ID = A.ID AND  A.YEAR < YEAR4
INNER JOIN TABLE5 T5 ON T5.ID = A.ID AND  A.YEAR1 < YEAR5
INNER JOIN TABLE6 T6 ON T6.ID = A.ID AND  A.YEAR1 < YEAR6
```

Pls check your SQL, year5 is compared twice.